# Probleme accessing url via volley

Tags: android, authentication, android-volley

I'm trying to get a json via an url.
When I'm trying to access the url via my navigator, it's work perfectly. But when I'm trying to access it via volley I got this error :

```
02-26 17:07:57.706 15056-15125/com.perso.simon.ulr_geoloc E/Volley: [5254] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for ...
02-26 17:07:57.716 15056-15125/com.perso.simon.ulr_geoloc E/Volley: [5254] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for ...
02-26 17:07:57.719 15056-15056/com.perso.simon.ulr_geoloc E/error: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
```

I dont't see where the error can be.

Here's my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    if(!isConnectedInternet(SplashScreenActivity.this)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreenActivity.this);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_box_confirmation, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_box_text).setTitle(R.string.dialog_box_title);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        StringRequest requestBat = new StringRequest(urlBat, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("test", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("error", error.toString());
            }
        });

        requestBat.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SplashScreenActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(requestBat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in you'r question you say : 'I'm trying to get a json via an url'

but in you'r code you wirte 'StringRequest' . i think if you change StringRequest to `JsonRequest` problem solve.

Comment: Unfortunately, problem not solved, the error is still the same. If you have other idea ...

Comment: is this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) there are some reason to why 403 error happen . maybe problem is from api